# How to get two query results from the same table column for height and weight

Tags: mysql

I have a table that essentially contains both **height**, **weight** and date of students (**sid**).  The **height** and **weight** are contained in the same column: `'Percent'` and an enum column contains height and weight.
Entries for both have the exact same date:

```
-- Table structure and sample data for table `PROGWandH`
--
CREATE TABLE `wandh` (
  `Wid` int(24) NOT NULL,
  `sid` int(4) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `level` enum('height','weight') NOT NULL,
  `Percent` decimal(5,1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `PROGWandH` (`Wid`, `sid`, `date`, `level`, `Percent`) VALUES
(157, 55, '2020-01-13 15:00:00', 'weight', '20.2'),
(131, 55, '2019-12-12 15:00:00', 'weight', '19.8'),
(121, 55, '2019-11-14 15:00:00', 'weight', '19.3'),
(774, 55, '2020-01-13 15:00:00', 'height', '113.0'),
(749, 55, '2019-12-12 15:00:00', 'height', '112.0'),
(739, 55, '2019-11-14 15:00:00', 'height', '111.5');
--
ALTER TABLE `wandh`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`Wid`);
```

I'm trying to generate a list with columns height, width and date.  The PHP I use generates one set each, one after the other, but I need to generate the list as height, weight, date, height, weight, etc.
What I've tried so far generates duplicates, so the output isn't synced:

```
select Percent, s1.Percent1, date
from wandh
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT Percent as 'Percent1' from wandh where level = 'weight' and sid = 55) as s1
      where sid = 55 and level = 'height';
```

and

```
select Percent, s1.Percent1, date
from wandh JOIN (SELECT Percent as 'Percent1' from wandh where level = 'weight' and sid = 55) as s1
      on date where sid = 55 and level = 'height';
```

Other variations I've tried don't work.

```
select level, Percent, date from wandh where level like '%eight' and sid = 55;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
select sid, date,
  max(case when level = 'weight' then percent end) weight,
  max(case when level = 'height' then percent end) height
from wandh
group by sid, date
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n984w4RJ1GrW8biDQLRKqF/0).
Results:

```
| sid | date                | weight | height |
| --- | ------------------- | ------ | ------ |
| 55  | 2019-11-14 15:00:00 | 19.3   | 111.5  |
| 55  | 2019-12-12 15:00:00 | 19.8   | 112    |
| 55  | 2020-01-13 15:00:00 | 20.2   | 113    |
```

Comment: OMG thank you!  fits perfectly. You just saved our students' graduating chart page!